# How to IOS Submit App for Review at App Store After It Shows in Activity Tab

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

About a month ago, I submitted and app to the App store and it was rejected.  I then "distributed" a revised version to the app store using Xcode. I was under the impression, I was submitting it for review and I think I submitted it twice now the same way I submitted it the first time. The new build is plainly visible in the Activity Tab as well as is the older version which shows Rejected under status and the first revision I attempted to submit.

I have messaged Apple twice about what is going on with my new build 6. In their latest message they suggested I had uploaded something for testing instead of review.  Here is the full thread from the resolution center:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for providing your response.
>
> Regarding Build 6, it is possible you have uploaded a build for
>   testing instead of submitted the build for review.
>
> To resolve this issue, it would be appropriate to submit your app for
>   review.
>
> All of the necessary documentation on submitting builds can be found
>   in App Store Connect Developer Help.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review
>
> Apr 11, 2019 at 5:53 PM From me Hello, Please see Build 6 in the
>   Activity Tab. Are you reviewing this Build or what is the status? Apr
>   11, 2019 at 5:44 PM From Apple
>
> Hello,
>
> Thank you for making the requested changes. You will need to submit a
>   new build for review.
>
> More information about submitting builds can be found in App Store
>   Connect Developer Help.
>
> We look forward to reviewing your resubmitted app.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

At the top of list of builds under Activity it says:

iOS Builds
All builds that have been submitted for iOS. Version numbers are the Xcode version numbers.

Below is a picture.

As far as I could tell I submitted the App for Review but Apple is saying I did not.  Given that it appears in Activity, what else can I do to submit it for review?

Note: I tried hovering over the build number of the rejected version for a red dot to appear as some answers suggest but no red do appeared.

[image]

Comment: You uploaded app on app store but you need to submit it.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Have you ever replaced your old build with new one and submitted app again?

Comment: No.  I think I figured it out.  I need to click on the Rejected version and then delete the old build.  Once I did that, it took the new build.

Comment: and dont forget to submit from here.